# EF-Migration: Ignore parts of model for overlapping bounded context

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

I'm working on a project (API) where I have several microservices sharing a database (.NET Core 2.2 and SQL Server 2017). As a result, sometimes my context will have overlapping dbsets. I should also mention that I'm using code first approach.

The thing is that I would like to ignore some dbsets that are included in my dbcontext to handle the migration in their original microservice.

So I have a `SearchService`, a `ResearchService` and an `AuthorService`. The `SearchService` looks for what the author created in the last year, but only gets basic info, `ResearchService` gets in depth info about the creations for the author and `AuthorService` gets statistics about the author and their work.

So both `ResearchService` and `AuthorService` use a `dbset<SearchedCreations>` that originally belonged to `SearchService`, along with their own dbsets `ResearchCreations` and `Author`, respectively.

I've been researching options in the last few days and I came across `modelBuilder.Ignore<SearchedCreations>`. But the thing is that if I do that in the `OnModelCreating` method, then I will not be able to query `DbSet<SearchedCreations>` at runtime. I will be ignored all the way, not just during migrations.

So, I found someone who said use the process name to test if it is migrations and then `modelBuilder.Ignore` like this:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.ToLower() == "ef")
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<SearchedCreations>();
}
```

That worked very well while I was doing .net core 2.0, but it seems that now the process was renamed and I don't know to which name. But in any event I feel like that is too unstable and took anther route...

I decided to add a public property `isRuntime` and set it to false by default. In this manner the previous code would look like this

```
if (!isRuntime)
{
     modelBuilder.Ignore<SearchedCreations>();
}
```

And it would satisfy my requirement to ignore SearchedCreations during migrations and not during runtime. But my problem is I don't know where or how to set `isRuntime = true` to make this work. I thought to do it in the constructor of my repository before the first use, but it seems to be too late because the context has already ignored SearchedCreations for good.

Here is a bit more of my code in case it helps
in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     //other things that are irrelevant
     var connectionString = Startup.Configuration["connectionStrings:conStrExpress"];
     services.AddScoped<IResearchCreationsRepository, ResearchCreationsRepository>();
     services.AddDbContext<ResearchCreationsContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
```

in ResearchCreationsContext.cs

```
public class ResearchCreationsContext: DbContext
    {
        public bool isRuntime { get; set; } = false;
        public DbSet<ResearchCreations> researchCreations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SearchedCreations> searchedCreations { get; set; }

        public ResearchCreationsContext(DbContextOptions<ResearchCreationsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            if (!isRuntime)
            {
                modelBuilder.Ignore<SearchedCreations>();
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is when and where should I set `isRuntime = true` in order to make this work?

Thanks in advance and I'm very sorry for the long post. It is my first. I promise to do better next time =)

Comment: or what other ideas do you guys have to comply with my requirement? I'm totally open

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Comment: thanks @SteveGreene, but unfortunately as I mentioned if I just do 
`protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

        {
                modelBuilder.Ignore<SearchedCreations>();
        }`
as the article suggests I would not be able to query `DbSet<SearchedCreations> searchedCreations` and I need to. That is why I need to have the ignore there only during the creation of the migration script. And I know that I could just comment and uncomment as needed but that is neither ideal or a solution